# How do I get GPG public key details without gnupg in PHP?

Tags: php, gnupg, public-key, pgp

I've got public key generated with GPG tool:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=ObbS
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

How can I get details of this key in PHP without using gnupg library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either:

1. Use the PGP specifications and write your own implementation (potentially very difficult).
2. Use a different library.